# Get ALL Facebook posts using facebook api and paging

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

It's my intention to get all past posts. I have created a Facebook app. When this code is executed, I have properly logged in with the correct appid and secret.

```
function loadPage() {   // calls the first batch of records
   FB.api("/me/feed",{},function(response) { procBatch(response) } );
   }

function procBatch(dat) { // handle this batch, request the next batch
   for ( i = 0; i < dat.data.length; i++ ) {
      procRow(dat.data[i]);  // process this row
      }
   if ( typeof(dat.paging) != 'undefined' ) {
      FB.api(dat.paging.next, {}, function(response){ procBatch(dat); } );
      } else {
      alert("No more records expected");
      }
   }
```

Unfortunately, this only takes me back about six months.

Is it possible to go back further?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

This can be done by increasing the **limit** of number object per page. I've not tried retrieving ALL the posts, but I am pretty sure that you can easily retrieve posts which are even few years old.

You can call `/me/feed?limit=numberOfObjectsPerPage` instead of just `/me/feed` to increase this limit.

You can find more information on this [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/). Do have a look at the **Time Based Pagination** on the link. This will explain you how to manage the output for the feeds.

Comment: I increased the limit to 200, and it worked.  Can't believe I missed that.  Thank you VERY MUCH for your help.

Comment: This is the first time I've asked for help here.  I've accepted the answer. If there is any other way I can add to your reputation, please let me know and I'll do it.  I wrote this three different ways using different APIs getting the same results.

Again, thank you.

Comment: It seems like new version of Facebook API has limitation to 100 objects per page. But we can omit that by using next page token and loop.